# Newby at code, and can not figure out how to get my answer in the correct place

Tags: javascript

I have this working...mostly. I am trying to get it to put the answer into the "results" box (which shows up on the right). It returns the correct answer, but into the same box that the original number was inputted.

```default-markup
<script language="JavaScript">
<!-- 
function process()
{
  var formObj = document.getElementById("squarenumber");
  var number = formObj.number.value;
  {
    formObj.number.value = Math.pow(number, 2);
  }
}
// -->
</script>
<form name="number" id="squarenumber">
  <input type="text" name="number">
  <input type="button" value="compute" onclick="process(squarenumber)">
  <input type="text" name="result">
</form>
```

Comment: First, java !== Javascript

Comment: You're using the same form field `number` when getting and setting the value. If you want it in the `result` field, then use `formObj.result.value = Math.pow(...`

Comment: ...and by the way, when you do this `onclick="process(squarenumber)"`, you're passing the form element into the function, but you're not actually using what you passed. In some browsers, it will break because the elements are not defined as global variables. You should probably just do `onclick="process()"`, or if you really want to pass the form, then `onclick="process(this.form)"`

Answer (score 1):

In your assignment you need to reference the `result` text item:

```
formObj.result.value = Math.pow(number, 2);
```